# Submitting a Docusign document via email instead of a WebService

Tags: docusignapi

I realize it's a long shot but thought I'd ask anyway. Is it possible to submit a PDF Document to DocuSign as an email Attachment, instead of using REST api or even SOAP api?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing is a module called the **DocuSign Print Driver**.

Here's a description of what it does, and a link to the guide.

`The DocuSign Print Driver is a tool that allows you to “print” your document directly into a new DocuSign envelope from the application that created/opens it. It saves you time by eliminating the need to save, launch a browser session, create a new envelope and upload. The Print Driver does all of this in one-step.`

[Print Driver Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/quick-start-print-driver.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Ergin. Definitely an interesting product. Probably more geared towards the client end of things, whereas my need is more on the server side. But still good to know about it.